# $2+3+5+9+8+15+11+21+14+27+17+\dots$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

I need to find the sum of the series upto $2n+1$ term

$2+3+5+9+8+15+11+21+14+27+17+\dots$

so $2,5,8,11,14,17\dots$ is one AP and $3,9,15\dots$ is another AP

I just want to know From which AP I should take $n$ terms and $n+1$ terms to find the final sum?

Comment: The $2,5,8,\dots$ part has $n+1$ terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(2n+1)$ is odd, so the last term in given series should be the term in the series $2,5,8,..$.

So you take:$(n+1)$ terms from $2,5,8,11,...$ and $n$ terms from $3,9,15,...$